# Can't access a class variable from AlertDialog

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a StatefulWidget named HomePage with a class variable named _messages.

```
class HomePageState extends State<HomePage>{
    final List<Msg> _messages = <Msg>[];
...
```

I also have a IconButton which will popup a dialog which has a FlatButton that when pressed, it will clear all items inside the _messages variable.

```
void showMyPopup() async{
    return showDialog(
        content: FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
                setState((){
                    _messages = [];
...
```

But flutter/dart gave me an error which says HomePage doesn't have _messages variable.

I can access the _messages when I'm not on the dialog, but not within the dialog.

I would like to know what was wrong with my code. I would really appreciate any form of help.

Comment: you can't edit a final variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `widget._messages` and please don't make your variable final. final is final, it cannot be changed.

---